# Custom roll fix effects in regressions

Tags: python, r, statistics, regression

In a regressions, I know instead of using fixed effects (say on country or year), you can specify these effects with dummy variables and this is a perfectly legitimate method. However, when the number of effects (e.g. countries) is large, then it becomes very computational difficult. Instead you would run the fixed effects model. I am curious what R's `plm` or Stata's `xtreg,fe` does behind the scenes. Specifically, I wanted to try custom rolling my own panel regression...looking for some likelihood function (or way to condition the likelihood) I can throw into `optim` and have some fun. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

how `plm` and `xtreg,fe`do behind the screen are well documented in their instructions, I didn't read them through but I think that when  you run `pgmm` or some thing like `logit regression` in `plm`,the algorithm actually is maximum likelihood given the nature of these problems.

and it would be interesting to write all these by yourself.